# Does the PCI bus for a device remain the same across mulitple computers that have the same BIOS, Operating System, and in the same PCIe slot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, pci-express, bus

My operating system is windows 10. I have a bat file that calls a device based on the bus number. This bat file will be copied to each PC and then cannot be changed. There are more then one of the same device in the machine so device ID won't work to distinguish the devices. My question is will the PCI bus (seen in device manager->General->Location:) be the same on each computer. As of right now they are all the same but I can't guarantee that will always happen. The computers will all have the same BIOS and same image of the operating system. The devices will always be in the same PCIe slots. Any links or sources where I can guarantee bus will remain the same would be great. Thanks ahead of time.

[Device Manager PCI bus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5koMJ.png)

The circled PCIe bus is the number I find the device by and is the number I would need to be the same. This isn't the device I am concerned about and my device is also PCIe not usb. Also I am making my device so the are no drivers for it on google.

Comment: Are we talking about the same motherboard model number or multiple brands and models?  The majority of OEM equipment uses the same firmware across all their product lines, that is the reason, I asked my question.

Comment: Same motherboard.

Comment: If you mean the BUS Device ID, this is something that is tied to the card. You can use it to google what an unknown device is to find its drivers. But I'm not entirely sure if this is what you mean. Could you post an example of a bus ID? (also, google it and if you get your device, then you know its going to be the same)

Comment: Here's an example of my GPU: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&CC_0300

Comment: This property can change depending on whether/where other PCIe cards are installed. Dunno why you’d want to depend on that.

Comment: The kernel part returns that as one of the values. Having more then one of the same device in the PC leaves that as about the only different value. Having the program already use that returned value and it working, trying to avoid a modification. Everything is the same between multiple computers, new devices should not get added. Safe to assume that value will be the same between the computers?

Comment: It's of course fine to uniquely identify multiple devices of the same type, but again: Why? There's no need to hardcode something like that.